# When I do not add an activation function to my convolutional layer the model gets quickly stuck in a local optima, why?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, activation-function

I have model A:

```
model = Sequential()
tuple_kernel_size = (3, 3)
pool_size = (2, 2)

model.add(Conv2D(32, tuple_kernel_size, activation='relu', input_shape=(input_dim, input_dim, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size))
model.add(Conv2D(64, tuple_kernel_size))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(Dense(units=32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
```

As you can see the second Conv2D layer does not have an activation function set. This is the performance of that model during training. As you can see the accuracy is mostly stuck around 0.5 (is it a binary classification problem with balanced classes).

[image]

However when I add the `relu` activation function to the second conv layer and leave the rest the same. The model trains much much better, what is going on here? Could someone provide an intuitive understanding of why adding an activation function here matters that much for performance. The loss also keeps dropping while it is stuck around 0.7 for the model without the activation function. Thanks!!
[image: Model B Performance]

Comment: Not using an activation function means that the output of the convolution layer's output is a (masked) linear combination of the input. Linear networks are not very expressive, so it's not surprising that this model does not fit the data very well. The downsides to linear networks are explained in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228296/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-neural-network-activation-function/236386#236386.